# Is it possible to save files to a network path?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, path, unc, network-share

I was wondering if it would be possible to write a file, not to the local system, but to a connected server or other network path.

Would I have to use an external interface for this or can I entrust this to the AIR framework?

I'm pretty sure that AIR has certain security precautions to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of network path? SMB, FTP, HTTP, WebDav, .. ?

If it's mounted on your local PC, then you should be able to write to it just like writing to any other drive or filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

to write a new file to a folder on a networked drive in OSX:

```
var targetDir:File = new File("/Volumes/Data/SomeFolder");
targetDir.createDirectory();  // ensure directory exists, create if not
var targetFile:File = targetDir.resolvePath("newFile.ext");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
try {
    fileStream.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(byteArray);  // or what/however you want to write
    fileStream.close();
} catch (e:Error) {
    trace(e);
}
```

i assume for Windows you would just swap the network drive path in the first line.  you should not specify a protocol (e.g. file://, smb://, etc); the format of the parameter for the File constructor is the native path (as it would appear in a terminal / command shell).

to get the path in OSX, use the Finder to navigate to the target networked folder.  begin dragging the folder somewhere else, hit apple+space to open Spotlight, and continue dragging the folder into Spotlight.  alternately, open a Terminal window and drag the folder into the Terminal window.

Comment: `new File('\\networkpath\file.png')` throws an `IOErrorEvent: URL not found`, but the copy is successful anyway.